# get the return of a function with multiple returns

Tags: solidity

How can i get the a and b from the following function:

```
function f() returns (uint a, uint b){

}

funtion g(){
    uint s = f();
}
```

do i need to just use one return parameter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use double return in a function.

To get the returned value in your example use:

```
  uint256 c;
  uint256 d;
  (c,d) = f();
```